# How this method returns different type than declared?

Tags: kotlin

I found the following code in a project and it is used to convert throwables to custom exceptions.

I am confused how it is working.

The expected return type is: `Single<out Response<T>>`

But the method body returns something different: eg `Single<Exception>`

Is there explanation? it is compiling and working fine!

```
class ThrowableObservableFunc1<T> : Function1<Throwable, Single<out Response<T>>> {

    override fun invoke(throwable: Throwable): Single<out Response<T>> {
        val clientConnectionException = Exception(throwable.message)

        return when (throwable) {
            is ConnectException, is UnknownHostException, is SSLException ->
                Single.error(clientConnectionException)
            is SocketTimeoutException ->
                Single.error(TimeoutConnectionException(throwable.message))
            else -> Single.error(UnexpectedException(throwable.message))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Single.error` doesn't return a `Single<Exception>`, it returns a `Single<T>` according to its signature:

```
public static <T> Single<T> error(final Throwable exception)
```

Since the `T` type parameter isn't used anywhere in the signature other than in the return type (that is to say, it doesn't take a `T` as a parameter, for example), it can be inferred to whatever type you need returned from this function wrapped into a `Single`.

For some more examples:

```
val stringError: Single<String> = Single.error(Exception()) // T inferred to be String
val intError: Single<Int> = Single.error(Exception())       // T inferred to be Int
```

Or, if you want to specify the parameter when you're calling the function directly (in which case you could omit the types for the variables on the left hand side):

```
val stringError: Single<String> = Single.error<String>(Exception()) // T specified as String
val intError: Single<Int> = Single.error<Int>(Exception())       // T specified as Int
```

These all make sense because a `Single` of any type can error the exact same way, regardless of what type a non-errored value it produces would have.